# Renaming matrix rows in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have the following matrix:

```
> dat

       [,1]      [,2]       [,3]        [,4]
foo 0.7574657 0.2104075 0.02922241 0.002705617
foo 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.000000000
foo 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.000000000
foo 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.000000000
foo 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.000000000
foo 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.000000000
```

and given this:

```
> new_names <- c("f0","f1","f2","f3","f4","f5");
# where the length of new_names matches the number of rows in the dat matrix
```

How can I get this?

```
        [,1]      [,2]       [,3]        [,4]
f0 0.7574657 0.2104075 0.02922241 0.002705617
f1 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.000000000
f2 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.000000000
f3 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.000000000
f4 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.000000000
f5 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.000000000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
dat <- matrix(c(c(0.7574657, 0.2104075, 0.02922241, 0.002705617), rep(0, 4*6-4)), ncol = 4, nrow = 6, byrow = TRUE)

rownames(dat) <- paste0("f", seq(0, nrow(dat)-1))
```

If you already have a vector of names, then

```
rownames(dat) <- new_names
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> rownames(dat) <- c("f0","f1","f2","f3","f4","f5")

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.